# Pasting the column name to each value of a dataframe in R but only in one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to paste the column name to each cell, and I've found this answer in another post.

```
df[] <- paste(col(df, TRUE), as.matrix(df), sep = ":")
```

But how should I modify it, if I've just want to use only for the first column in a dataframe?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: `df[, 1] = paste0(colnames(df)[1],df[, 1])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this only for one column, you can do :

```
df[[1]] <- paste(df[[1]], names(df)[1], sep = ":")
```